# Odd behavior with urllib.request.urlopen in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I have been working through an online class on python with Coursera (this is not homework) and have been having a problem with urllib.request.urlopen for some urls. For the url hardcoded into the code below, the command urllib.request.urlopen(serviceurl, context=ctx).read().decode() times out.  If another url is used... say http://www.woot.com is used data is returned.

I have tried this on two separate Ubuntu machines at my location, both running 18.04 (with 3.6.7 which is default) and 3.7.3 via Anaconda.
I have even reinstalled Ubuntu with the same results.

Strangely, if I include a timeout parameter (for example, urllib.request.urlopen(serviceurl, timeout=1, context=ctx).read().decode()), data is returned.

Also, this program runs successfully (regardless of url) with no timeout parameter on a macbook air running 3.6.4

```
import urllib.request
import ssl


# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

address = input('Enter Locaton: ')
if len(address) < 1:
    serviceurl = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml?'
else:
    serviceurl = address

s = urllib.request.urlopen(serviceurl, context=ctx).read().decode()
print(s)
```

I seem to be the only one having this issue and it has me stumped.  I am  just beginning to get familiar with python (C, C#, Java are more familiar).  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answered (I think) my own question.  Looks like the website does not like IP6 sockets.  Was able to trace the hang back to socket.py.  First address used in create connection is an IP6 address and port which does not return anything.  Adding a timeout caused the code to select the next address and port from the list which was IP4 and that worked.  For the time being I disabled IP6 in Ubuntu 18.04 to force IP4 use.